# Evaluate $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{y\sin(x^2y)}{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Evaluate (if exists) $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{y\sin(x^2y)}{x^2+y^2}$.

$$\left|\frac{y\sin(x^2y)}{x^2+y^2}\right|\leq\left|\frac{x^2y^2}{x^2+y^2}\right|\leq\left|\frac{x^2y^2}{2xy}\right|=\left|\frac{xy}{2}\right|\to0.$$

But wolframalpha says: no. The limit doesn't exist. But is it really true? It would mean that $\sin(x^2y)$ cannot really be bounded by it's argument.

Comment: Your argument is correct and Wolframalpha is wrong.